# Firebird UDF that calls an external url

Tags: user-defined-functions, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm new to Firebird and just wanted to know if it's possible to create a UDF in Firebird that makes a GET call on a URL and how can I do this.

Comment: Can you write native code that opens a URL? Then, if you write it appropriately to be callable as a UDF, it should work. That said, it would be recommended to upgrade to Firebird 3 (or 4) and use UDRs instead.

Comment: Bad idea, verily. It would at best be very slow with huge latency, at worst it would crash. Firebird engine is not expecting it, so it would have one of its threads (superserver) or processes (Classic/SuperClassic) stall for abnormally long hiatus. Which would make locks manager and all other internal arbitration/balancing framework be stressed to extreme. Internet access is by definition asynchronous and error-prone, database engine internals would be totally inapropriate place for such functions. You can take any FLOSS UDF library sources to use as tutorial, if aiming at shooting your foot